# Display only Y value in coordinate array

Tags: javascript

Im creating an array of coordinates like this:

```
var array = [[0,100], [(Range),130]];
```

where range is a user-defined number.

Im wondering if there is a method in JavaScript to output only the y values into a string or even using `console.log` so the output would look like **100, 130**

If anyone can help that would be great

Comment: **[Don't add language tags in your question's title.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)** Everyone else: A rollback war ain't gonna help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) may help you:

```
console.log( array.map(function(c) { return c[1]; }) );
```

**N.B.:** Check the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility) for this method and use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) if required.

Comment: OP, this will return an array. If you want a string use `join(',')` on the array.

Comment: @Andy With `console.log` it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @VisioN ooohh Ill try that give me a sec

Comment: @VisioN i wish i could vote up your answer but I joined StackOverflow a few days ago so dont have enough rep to vote up but thank you so much :) Bit of conflict with the Highcharts library when I drag and drop but im sure i can get around that.

Comment: @Danazar No worries, you may however accept the answer by clicking the tick if it solves your question.